# Can I grep for results compared to a timestamp?

Tags: linux, bash, grep, text-files

I have a tab-delimited text file with three fields: `TIMESTAMP`, `HOST`, and `STATUS`.  I need to find if a host was listed as down less than an hour ago.  So far, I have this example:

`grep "Down" thetextfile.txt | grep "thehostname"`

That gives me a little list of all the times that a host was down in the log.  Cool.  Now I think I just need to get whether the latest `TIMESTAMP` is less than an hour ago.  I am pretty new to Linux and Bash scripting, but in my other work with actual databases, this would be a relatively simple query.

Any ideas?  Or is there a much better approach?

Here's an example of the log file:

```
TIMESTAMP       HOST    STATUS
Wed Oct 8 12:16:23 EDT 2014      aserver       Alive
Wed Oct 8 12:16:23 EDT 2014      anotherserver     Down
```

Thanks!

Comment: Edited.  I also tried Awk and ended up in the same place, but that is probably because I don't know much about Awk yet.

Comment: Is it possible to have different timezones for different servers?

Comment: Nope.  They're all here in our building.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this BASH script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# current date-time in seconds (epoch) value
now=$(date '+%s')

while read -r p; do
    # ignore 1st row with headers
    [[ "$p" == *TIMESTAMP* ]] && continue

    # read 3 values in 3 variables t h s
    IFS=$'\t' && read t h s <<< "$p"

    # convert date string to epoch value
    ts=$(date -d "$t" '+%s')

    # if date from file is less than 1 hour ago and status is Down then print host name
    [[ "$s" == "Down" ]] && (( (now-ts) < 3600 )) && echo "$h"
done < file
```

Comment: I tweaked it a bit so that the conditional part is laid out in an `if` for the ease of other coworkers, but this worked out better than the `gawk` solution just because it fits our script more easily.  Nonetheless, both are cool ideas.  Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 2):

I'd use GNU awk:

```
gawk -v status=Down -v host=anotherserver '
    BEGIN {
        mo["Jan"]=1; mo["May"]=5; mo["Sep"]=9
        mo["Feb"]=2; mo["Jun"]=6; mo["Oct"]=10
        mo["Mar"]=3; mo["Jul"]=7; mo["Nov"]=11
        mo["Apr"]=4; mo["Aug"]=8; mo["Dec"]=12
    }
    function elapsed(month, day, time, year) {
        gsub(/:/, " ", time)
        return systime() - mktime(sprintf("%d %02d %02d %s", year, mo[month], day, time));
    }
    $NF == status && $(NF-1) == host && elapsed($2,$3,$4,$6) < 3600
' <<DATA
TIMESTAMP       HOST    STATUS
Wed Oct 8 12:16:23 EDT 2014      aserver       Alive
Wed Oct 8 12:16:23 EDT 2014      anotherserver     Down
Wed Oct 16 10:16:23 EDT 2014      aserver       Alive
Wed Oct 16 10:16:23 EDT 2014      anotherserver     Down
Wed Oct 16 10:16:23 EDT 2014      aserver       Down
Wed Oct 16 10:16:23 EDT 2014      anotherserver     Up
DATA
```

```
Wed Oct 16 10:16:23 EDT 2014      anotherserver     Down
```

Current date is Thu Oct 16 10:53:45 EDT 2014